# How to set the position of stage or window using clutter1.0?

Tags: c, linux, clutter

How to set the position of the stage or window using clutter1.0? Just like in opengl `glutInitWindowPosition(0, 500)`. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Clutter does not provide a wrapper around windowing system specific API: the Stage, as a scene graph element, is defined to always be at (0, 0), so you cannot use the ClutterActor set_position() method on it.

if you're on X11, you can use the X11 API to move a stage Window, e.g.:

```
  Display *xdpy = clutter_x11_get_default_display ();
  Window xwin = clutter_x11_stage_get_window (stage);

  XMoveWindow (xdpy, xwin, 0, 500);
```

obviously, there's the whole thorny issue of manual window placement in X11: you should not really do that, and you should defer to the window manager to actually position your windows.

on Windows, you can get the WHND of the Stage window using `clutter_win32_get_stage_window()` and use `SetWindowPos()` similarly to how it works on X11.

on OS X is a bit trickier, as Clutter does not expose the NSWindow nor the NSView used by the Stage, as of yet, so you'll have to hack a bit inside Clutter.

Comment: obviously, I should also mention that you could use the clutter-gtk library, and GtkWindow API for window size and positioning.

Comment: tnx... maybe i'll use gtk for positioning the window. thanks a lot... :D